# Evaluating $\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }\:\frac{x^k}{k!\cdot \left(2+k\right)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

My work so far was noticing that it is similar to the MacLaurin expansion of $e^x$ but I am stuck

Comment: You can use $\frac{x^k}{k+2}=x^{-2}\int_0^xt^{k+1}dt$ or also notice $k!(k+2)=\frac{(k+2)!}{k+1}$

Comment: thank you but idk how am i supposed to use that?

Comment: Multiply series on $x^2$ and take derivative.

Comment: You know $e^x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's $f(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!\cdot (k+2)}$, then $g(x)=x^2 \cdot f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k+2}}{k!\cdot (k+2)}$

$$g'(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k+1}}{k!}=xe^x$$
Now it remains to solve the equation and the areas of applicability of the operations performed. I hope you can handle this, but if not, write where you encounter difficulties.